# Using sed command to change each letter to the next one in the alphabet

Tags: bash, sed

Here is what is the file beast.txt:
savage
beast
tank
beauty

I am looking to get it to look like:
tbwbhf
cfbtu
ubol
cfbvuz

This what I have but when I run this it changes the letters to "[a-z]+1".

cat beast.txt | sed 's/[a-z]/[a-z]+1/g' > savage.txt

Do I have to use other special characters to in the sed command or should this be done with a loop? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza/' beast.txt > savage.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a job for sed:

```
$ echo 'savage beast tank beauty' | tr a-z b-za
tbwbhf cfbtu ubol cfbvuz
```

If you really want to use sed, you can do:

```
$ b2z=bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
$ echo 'savage beast tank beauty' | sed -e "y/a$b2z/${b2z}a/"
tbwbhf cfbtu ubol cfbvuz
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you were right it worked perfectly...I appreciate your help!!

Comment: What tr command  sequence would change it back since z-a will give me an error?

Comment: To convert back, you could do `tr b-za a-z`

Answer (score 0):

I used this '$ echo 'savage beast tank beauty' | tr a-z b-za' and it worked.

I am now having trouble reversing what I just did.

Comment: `tr b-za a-z` to undo. Check with `echo 'savage beast tank beauty' | tr a-z b-za | tr b-za a-z`

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was putting 'tr a-z z-a' and getting an error. This solution was perfect, I appreciate it.